# Enabling Case.IsSelfServiceClosed on Dev Org?

Tags: deployment

I'm deploying a bunch of meta data, including profiles from an EE to a Developer org.  I'm currently running into a dependency in the profiles referencing Case.IsSelfServiceClosed .  it doesn't exist on the developer org.  Is there a way of enabling this field?  Or am I stuck manually modifying the profile meta data on the source org after every update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Setup > Customer Portal > Enable Customer Portal, and create a new one. That should avail the fields.

Comment: Thanks, user320.  I solved this by simply not including Case in my package.xml in eclipse.  This prevented the profiles from having Case related meta data.  However, this seems like a equally good alternative, so I'll accept it.

Comment: I have community enabled. Isn't it enough? Should I also enable Customer Portal (which is obsolete)